# Selenium fails on ECS

Tags: docker, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, containers, amazon-ecs

this is my **Dockerfile** code

```
    FROM --platform=Linux/X86_64 node:16
    RUN apt update
    RUN apt -y install build-essential
    RUN apt -y install wget
    RUN wget -q -O - https://dl-ssl.google.com/linux/linux_signing_key.pub | apt-key add - \ 
        && echo "deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/google.list
    RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install google-chrome-stable
    
    
    
    # COPY --from=CHORMEBUILDER /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
    # Create app directory
    COPY $PWD /crm-connector
    WORKDIR /crm-connector
    
    # RUN npm install --location=global npm@8.12.1
    # Install app dependencies
    # A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
    # where available (npm@5+)
    COPY package*.json ./
    RUN node -v
    RUN npm uninstall chromedriver
    RUN npm install 
    RUN npm install chromedriver --chromedriver-force-download --detect_chromedriver_version
    # If you are building your code for production
    #RUN npm ci --only=production
    
    # Bundle app source
    COPY . .
    
    
    RUN npm run build
    
    EXPOSE 8081
    CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

I'm trying to run this on ECS

I've hosted my code(Docker images) ECR.

I'm getting following error.

> selenium error ex Error: Server terminated early with status 2
> at /crm-connector/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/remote/index.js:248:24

Build taken machine is: Mac M1

Trying to deploy it on **Operating system/Architecture
Linux/X86_64**

Task Definition is:

```
{
    "containerDefinitions": [
        {
            "image":"image-name",
            "logConfiguration": {
                "logDriver": "awslogs",
                "options": {
                    "awslogs-group": "all-log",
                    "awslogs-region": "us-east-1",
                    "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
                }
            },
            "name":"task-name",
            "portMappings": [
                {
                    "containerPort": 8081,
                    "hostPort": 8081,
                    "protocol": "tcp",
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "cpu": "8192",
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::accountId:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "family":"task-family",
    "memory": "32768",
    "networkMode": "awsvpc",
    "runtimePlatform": {
        "operatingSystemFamily": "LINUX"
    },
    "requiresCompatibilities": [
        "EC2",
        "FARGATE"
    ]
}
```

advanced thanks for any help you guys do. :)

Comment: Dockerfiles don't start with `#!/bin/bash` and they aren't indented like that. Besides that, have you actually tried building and running this docker image locally before deploying to AWS?

Comment: I haven't had "#!/bin/bash" at start recently I've added it because some forums said so.  BTW same file works on EBS. and indent happened while pasting on stackover flow. in local I can't test, because I have mac M1

Comment: By EBS, do you mean AWS Elastic Block Store? Or are you trying to refer to AWS Elastic Beanstalk?

Comment: no, elastic beanstalk

Comment: WARNING: The requested image's platform (linux/amd64) does not match the detected host platform (linux/arm64/v8) and no specific platform was requested. 
I always get this error. So I never run on my laptop

Comment: It sounds like you selected ARM deployment for your ECS task, instead of X86., but you are building an X86 image.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251292/discussion-between-vivek-aasaithambi-and-mark-b).

Answer (score 0):

It was the architecture difference issue. Building machine was arm64 and ECS X86.

if you build from different architecture, remove node_modules and add `FROM platform=dest_architecture node:16` in Dockerfile

Thank you very much for the help
@Mark B